# Query to find ranges of consecutive rows

Tags: sql, gaps-and-islands, set-based

I have file that contains a dump of a SQL table with 2 columns: int ID (auto increment identity field) and bit Flag.  The flag = 0 means a record is good and the flag = 1 means a record is bad (contains an error). The goal is to find all blocks of consecutive bad records (with flag value of 1) with 1,000 or more rows.  The solution shouldn't use cursors or while loops and it should use the set-based queries only (selects, joins etc). 
We would like to see the actual queries used and the results in the following format:

```
StartID – EndID    NumberOfErrorsInTheBlock
StartID – EndID    NumberOfErrorsInTheBlock
……………………….
StartID – EndID    NumberOfErrorsInTheBlock
```

For example if our data were only 30 records and we were looking for blocks with 5 or more records then the results would look as follows (see the screenshot below, the errors blocks that met the criteria are highlighted) :

[ID Range].....[Number of errors in the block]

11-15.....             5

19-25.....            7

[sql file containing sample rows, dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ezjyyp04nnrrpyy/sql.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: What did you tried ? Stack is not code writing service.

Comment: After you have showed us what you tried, you also need to specify your RDBMS.  A solution for mySQL will probably be different than one for Postgress.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

### T-SQL Solution for SQL Server 2012 and Above

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tbl_ranges') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tbl_ranges;

CREATE TABLE #tbl_ranges
(
    row_num INT PRIMARY KEY,
    ID INT,
    Flag BIT,
    Label TINYINT
);

WITH cte_yourTable
AS
(
    SELECT  Id,
            Flag,
            CASE
                --label min
                WHEN Flag != LAG(flag,1) OVER (ORDER BY ID) THEN 1
                --inner 
                WHEN Flag = LAG(flag,1) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AND Flag = LEAD(flag,1) OVER (ORDER BY ID) THEN 2
                --end
                WHEN Flag = LAG(flag,1) OVER (ORDER BY ID) AND Flag != LEAD(flag,1) OVER (ORDER BY ID) THEN 3
            END label
    FROM yourTable
)

INSERT INTO #tbl_ranges
    SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) row_num,
            ID,
            Flag,
            label
    FROM cte_yourTable
    WHERE label != 2;

SELECT  A.ID ID_start,
        B.ID ID_end,
        B.ID - A.ID range_cnt
FROM #tbl_ranges A
INNER JOIN #tbl_ranges B
ON A.row_num = B.row_num - 1
AND A.Flag = B.Flag;

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tbl_ranges') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #tbl_ranges;
```

Abbreviated Results:

```
ID_start    ID_end      range_cnt
----------- ----------- -----------
2           3           1
5           8           3
9           10          1
11          35          24
36          356         320
357         358         1
359         406         47
...
```

Comment: I'd recommend changing #tbl_ranges to a common table expression computed using the select statement which insert into @tbl_ranges.  This will allow the solution to be completed in a single query with no need for DDL.

Comment: Yes I did originally have it as a CTE, but after the I changed it to a temp table, execution time was lower and so were logical reads so I kept it as a temp table

Answer (score 0):

With out using Temp Table, This is the best solution, Here is the Answer and It is perfect example for CTE with in CTE ( Nested CTE )

```
With Evaluation (ID,Flag,Evaluate)
as 
(select ID,Flag,Evaluate = ID-row_number() over (order by Flag,ID)
    from [dbo].[SqltestRecordsNew]
    where Flag = 1
    ),
Evaluation_Final (StartingRecordID,EndRecordID,Flag,cnt)
as
(
    select min(ID) as StartingRecordID,max(ID) as EndRecordID, 
    Flag, cnt = count(*)
    from    Evaluation
    group by Evaluate, Flag
)
select Concat(StartingRecordID,' - ', EndRecordID) as 'StartingRecordID - EndRecordId',
cnt as GroupItemCnt from Evaluation_Final
where cnt > 999
order by Concat(StartingRecordID,' - ', EndRecordID) 


-- Test results Case 1
Select ID,Flag, 
Case when Flag=1 then 'Success'
     else 'Defect Data'
End as TestResults
from SqltestRecordsNew
where ID between 1494363 and 1495559

-- Test results Case 2
Select ID,Flag,
Case when Flag=1 then 'Success'
     else 'Defect Data'
End as TestResults from SqltestRecordsNew
where ID between 1498409 and 1503899

-- Test results Case 3
Select ID,Flag,
Case when Flag=1 then 'Success'
     else 'Defect Data'
End as TestResults from SqltestRecordsNew
where ID between 1548257 and 1550489
```